# What is the default value of an array?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm creating a table of an arrays where the user can input the value themselves, and I will show them the table of value except the number `0` is use to exit from the `scanf`

so I don't want number `0` to be store in the array

but I'm seeing number `0` for the next value of an array so I'm wondering if `0` is a default value of an array.

to make it a bit more clear

let say the user entered;

5
4
3
2

### 1

and `0`

so what I suppose to show in my program output is

5
4
3
2
1

which I use array to display the index of 0-4 [1-5]

but just to make sure if number `0` is not store so I call array[5] to see if the next value is `0` or something else and it always display `0` so I want to know if there is a way to make sure that `0` is not going to store in the array

this is what I use to make sure

`if(enter != 0){`

`array[i - 1] = enter;`

Sorry if my question is complicated.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is needlessly complicated, it's hard to tell what you are asking. Can you make it clearer ?

Comment: Are you asking what an uninitialized array will contain? That's undefined.

Comment: My question would be like if they entered 5 numbers and stored in array and if I call the 6th number of the array what is that number going to be

since the 6th number is an exit number which is `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I revide my answer. Every array that you allocate can contain garbage, or not. The compiler *can* clear it for you, or not. In your case, I would clear the array with something like -1. Else you will have some undefined values in there, that be 0 or not. It's just not defined, every compiler can behave differently.

Test it:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void array(void);

int main(void) {
    int c[10], i;
    printf("Array 1: ");
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d", c[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    array();
    int b[10];
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d ",b[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void array(void) {
    int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
    return;
}
```

Comment: No, in C automatic storage duration variables are not initialized.

Comment: Thanks I have change your code a bit since it was an error and I can see what you mean now thanks.

Comment: @Ali: I just approved your edit.  But the previous version of the code was valid for C99 (which permits a variable to be declared in a for loop header), and the revised code is still invalid in C90, since it mixes declarations and statements.  To be valid in C90, you'd have to move all the declarations above all the statements.  To be valid in C99, it could have been left alone.

Comment: I actually used the --std=gnu99 as the compiler flag. Shame on me.

Answer (score 4):

If the array is with static storage duration it will be initialized to 0. In any other case, elements will not be initialized, i.e. will contain random bits.

Static storage duration have global variables, file scope static variables and block scope static variables.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, but generally arrays defined at compile-time are full of `0` by default. Arrays defined at run-time not necessarily, they could be `0` or full of crap.